# Can i overwrite visual studio community 2022 license from another computer?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I copied all visual studio community 2022 files from one computer to another, it is working good in the first computer, in the second computer, when I launch it, everything work good but it required prerelease software license!.
I signed to new account and trying to check for updates but the error message ("we could not download updated license , check your network connection or proxy").

How can I solve this?
Can I copy the license code or file or whatever from the other computer which works good?

Comment: You shouldn't be copying the program files from one computer to the other. Use the online installer to install it on the 2nd computer or use it to make an offline layout to install VS2022 without an internet connection.

Comment: Ok, but why the license doesn't work? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From visual studio 2019, the installation method has some changes. You can't copy visual studio from one pc to another directly. This way becomes more difficult than before. But still there are some ways to doing that. The best way which recommended in Microsoft documentation named offline installation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022 this will help you find some workaround solutions for your issues.

Comment: Thanks, but, dose it necessary to download the files from internet in the first installation?

Comment: If you didn't have a correct layout, yes it does

Comment: I had the same issue, and went into Apps, Modify and then Repair and that worked for me. After updates it said it was my first time and I just lost the recent locations.